# How to use regexp to grab elements of a tcl string

Tags: regex, tcl

I have extracted some data from a tabular column using "lsearch" and now have a TCL variable like this

```
{     1      no8  MASTER  (UP-DOWN)  ABCD     1456  /clown        F    right_left_123  /local/opt/data  WXYZ    (M5,N6)          }
```

How can I now use "regexp" to grab each of these values into separate variables? I guess I will have to filter by space, but the blank space between these values are variable.Also, I am a "regexp" newbie.

I tried using "lindex" but looks like the entire element is in index 0. Please let me know what is the easiest way.

Comment: Don't use regexp. Keep this rule-of-thumb in mind when working in Tcl: use string commands on strings and list commands on lists. That will truly make your life simpler.

Comment: Use `regexp` to parse strings from _outside_ Tcl, but once you've got a value from inside Tcl there are usually better approaches (as it is typically a list or a dictionary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsearch` has probably returned a list containing this 1 element. If you want to now get the elements inside this element, use a second index, to go 1 level deeper:

```
# suppose the list in in the variable $l
puts [lindex $l 0 0]
# => 1
puts [lindex $l 0 1]
# => no8
```

Comment: Ah, did not know you could use a second index to grab data out of a list with a single index. Thanks!

Comment: @user2045143 Yup! And you can add more if the list is deeper.

Comment: @user2045143, you will want a link to [the fine documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) -- check out the `lassign` command while you're in there, I think it will be suitable for what you're doing.